# How to reinvent measurement units?

Tags: science-based, physics

Imagine you're in deserted island. You will eventually need to know how much there is of something or how long is some thing.

Is there a way to get all main measurement units (kg, m, °C, m3, etc.) somehow? I know water freezes at 0 and boils at 100. Also G=9.8 and pi=3.14159. Also probably I could do something with pendulum, because I know G, but I wouldnt know time (from sunset to sunset 86400s?).

Are there some other valuable equations that could be used?

Comment: It seems like you're asking about actions of an individual in a pre-existing world rather than about establishing some fact of your fictional world.

Comment: It is 86,400 seconds (1) averaged over one full year (2) from noon to noon. Then a [seconds pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seconds_pendulum) is about 0.9936 meters long (but it varies a little bit with latitude and other factors). One cubic meter of water has a mass of 1,000 kilograms. And the question is a [duplicate](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/222795/how-to-recreate-units-of-measure).

Comment: Seems like someone on a deserted island would be far more concerned with basic survival needs than trying re-invent exact measurements.

Comment: @AlexP is correct, this is a duplicate (Other than this one is asking too many questions). Some of our units of measurement (like time) are very arbitrary. And if you don't know the specific gravity of the planet (little "g," not big "G") you can't derive it with a pendulum. And even if you did know it, if your character is capable of smelting metal and building gearing to the precision needed to get to a reasonable definition of a second, that's a remarkable person. (Besides, what's the point of known Earth seconds when your planet is unlikely to have an identical orbit?)

Answer (score 5):

You won't need to determine meter, second, kilogram. You will use your body and what you have around.

Being alone on a deserted island you will be the measure standard: your palm, your arm, your step, your thumb will do to take measure of lengths, since you will be the one measuring and also the one cutting.

For weight, you will do with volume measurements, if you can find some sort of standard container, or you will make the standard-ish volumes.

For time telling you can do with day counting and maybe a very simple hourglass if you really need it, but again, you won't need an atomic clock to measure the cooking time of game meat: "the time it takes for these 2 coconut shells full of water to drip out dry" will do. Worst case scenario, you can always count your heartbeats, if it did work for Galileo and his experiments, it will work for you.

Temperature, light intensity, current, mass... you won't have a use for them. Our world developed until the industrial revolution without them, you alone on a desert island will not miss them, either.

Standard units are useful if there are many parties involved into exchanging things that need to be measured, but for basic needs like you will have on a deserted island they are overly complicated. You will be too busy surviving to really worry about them.

Comment: Standard units are useful if you already know the values of interesting properties of interesting materials expressed in standard units.

Comment: All but heartbeats, as they might change frequency in a decently wide range (60-150, probably down to 40 if your straddler reaches meditation state). In fact "a coconut dripple" is a good enough time unit for such a person, early water-based hourglasses were precise enough to be used as a city-wide standard, and should you make one of these as a castaway, you can calibrate stuff by it, say a second half coconut in case the first one would change its internal volume.